# Importing 11 million rows from Postgresql to Pandas/Python

Tags: python, postgresql, optimization, bigdata, spyder

I am trying to load 11 million records from a PostgreSQL DB which is hosted on an AWS server. I have tried to use pandas read_sql, and I am getting the result in 4 hours. I have 32 GB of RAM on my laptop and also Core i7, 7th gen. I have also set the chunk size to 10000, but it does not improve the crazy time. I have looked at many articles online, and tried all of them but none of them speeds up my process. I want to ideally load this data under 20 minutes if possible or whatever is the shortest amount of time possible. I need this data in a dataframe so that I can do some merges with other files that I have, and if I can fetch the data in Python, I can automate my process. My code is displayed below:

```
from io import StringIO
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.sql as sql
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time


connection = psycopg2.connect(user="abc",
                                      password="efg",
                                      host="123.amazonaws.com",
                                      port="5432",
                                      database="db")

date='2020-03-01'
columns= '"LastName","FirstName","DateOfBirth","PatientGender","Key"'

postgreSQL_select_Query = 'select ' +  columns + ' from "Table" where "CreatedDate"::date>=' + "'" + date + "'" + 'limit 11000000'


x=pd.read_sql_query(postgreSQL_select_Query, connection, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, params=None, parse_dates=None, chunksize=10000)
```

Please suggest what I can do to improve this code, and reduce runtime.

I am also attaching another code segment, that I am using to do this, but the same result as it is fetching the rows in HOURS. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Second Approach:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

@author: ssullah
"""
from io import StringIO
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.sql as sql
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

start = time.time()
print("Started")

#Retreiving records from DB
def getdata():  
    try:
        start = time.time()
        print("Started")
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user="a"
                                      password="as",
                                      host="aws",
                                      port="5432",
                                      database="as")


        cur= connection.cursor()

        date='2020-03-01'
        columns= '"LastName","FirstName","DateOfBirth","PatientGender","Key"'

        postgreSQL_select_Query = 'select ' +  columns + ' from "ALLADTS" where "CreatedDate"::date>=' + "'" + date + "'" + 'limit 11000000'

        cur = connection.cursor('cursor-name') # server side cursor
        cur.itersize = 10000 # how much records to buffer on a client
        cur.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)

        mobile_records = cur.fetchall() 


    #Column names as per schema, defined above
        col_names=["LastName","FirstName","DateOfBirth","PatientGender","Key"]

    # Create the dataframe, passing in the list of col_names extracted from the description
        records = pd.DataFrame(mobile_records,col_names)

        return records;


    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error :
        print ("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)

    finally:
        #closing database connection.
        if(connection):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")


records=getdata()
end = time.time()
print("The total time:", (end - start)/60, 'minutes')
```

Comment: Could you try to retrieve the same data into a text file with the command line `psql`? If it takes the same time, then pandas or Python are out of the scope of the question and the problem is just the time to retrieve the data.

Comment: Is there any readon you can't summarize your data in POSTGRES before bringing it into pandas?

Comment: I can look into using psql for exporting it to a text file, if you have any references to this that would be great.

Comment: WombatPM: What kind of summarization are we talking about in potgres? I already am only fetching 4 columns out of the table, so that the data is smaller in size.

Comment: See \copy command, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY.  You would want to use the `\copy (<your query here>) to <filename>` form of the command.  On Linux, you can use /dev/null for the filename if you just want to fetch the data from the remote server without actually saving it.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Instead of loading data in Python, I decided to create a temporary table in postgresql using Python and load the new file from pandas to Postgresql. Once the table was populated using a query in python, I was able to query and get the desired output aas the final result back in the panda dataframe.

All of this took 1.4 minutes, and the same query takes 30 minutes to run in Pgadmin, so by leveraging Python, and doing the calculation using sql query written in Python, I was able to exponentially speed up the process, and at the same time not have to deal with 11 million records in my memory. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I did not understand load the new file from pandas to postgres. Can you please provide a code snippet if possible ?